# How does sklearn compute the precision_score metric?

Tags: scikit-learn

Hello I am working with sklearn and in order to understand better the metrics, I followed the following example of precision_score:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
    y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

    y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    print(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
```

the result that i got was the following:

```
0.222222222222
```

I understand that sklearn compute that result following these steps:

- for label 0 precision is tp / (tp + fp) = 2 / (2 + 1) = 0.66
- for label 1 precision is 0 / (0 + 2) = 0
- for label 2 precision is 0 / (0 + 1) = 0

and finally sklearn calculates mean precision by all three labels: `precision = (0.66 + 0 + 0) / 3 = 0.22`

this result is given if we take this parameters:

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

on the other hand if we take this parameters, changing average='micro' :

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
```

then we get:

```
0.33
```

and if we take average='weighted':

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
```

then we obtain:

```
0.22.
```

I don't understand well how sklearn computes this metric when the average parameter is set to 'weighted' or 'micro', I really would like to appreciate if someone could give me a clear explanation of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'micro'`:

Calculate metrics globally by considering each element of the label indicator matrix as a label.

`'macro'`:

Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This **does not take label imbalance** into account.

`'weighted'`:

Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average, **weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label)**.

`'samples'`:

Calculate metrics for each instance, and find their average.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html

For Support measures: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

Basically, class membership.

**3.3.2.12. Receiver operating characteristic (ROC)**

The function roc_curve computes the receiver operating characteristic curve, or ROC curve. Quoting Wikipedia :

“A receiver operating characteristic (ROC), or simply ROC curve, is a graphical plot which illustrates the performance of a binary classifier system as its discrimination threshold is varied. It is created by plotting the fraction of true positives out of the positives (TPR = true positive rate) vs. the fraction of false positives out of the negatives (FPR = false positive rate), at various threshold settings. TPR is also known as **sensitivity**, and FPR is one minus the **specificity** or true negative rate.”

TN / True Negative: case was negative and predicted negative.

TP / True Positive: case was positive and predicted positive.

FN / False Negative: case was positive but predicted negative.

FP / False Positive: case was negative but predicted positive# Basic terminology

```
confusion = metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted)
print confusion,"\n"
TN, FP    = confusion[0, 0], confusion[0, 1]
FN, TP    = confusion[1, 0], confusion[1, 1]

print 'Specificity:        ',  round(TN / float(TN + FP),3)*100, "\n"
print 'Sensitivity:        ',  round(TP / float(TP + FN),3)*100, "(Recall)"
```

Comment: thanks I already read it, but I would like to know what is weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label)?.

Comment: thanks but do you know if sklearn in the documentation define the Sensitivity and specificity?

Comment: thanks a lot for the support that is what I really needed.

Comment: I would suggest an example of each calculation. 
Like here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin

Comment: Let me add: micro average precision, in a multiclass single label context is non other than accuracy